# Xamarin.android Firebase add child (Data) not adding

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a new Item to my firebase database and I get an unhandled error which doesn't give me any indication as to why it failed.

Here is my activity page

```
public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        if (v.Id == Resource.Id.addnewcategory_btn_addcategory)
        {
            InsertNewCategory();
            StartActivity(new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(Categories)));
            Finish();
        }


    }

    private async void InsertNewCategory()
    {
        Category categories = new Category();
        categories.categoryId = String.Empty;
        categories.categoryName = input_newCategory.Text;

        var firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseURL);

        var item = await firebase.Child("categories").PostAsync<Category>(categories);

    }
```

My class is as follows

```
public class Category
{
    public string categoryId { get; set; }
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please suggest at which line did you code crash? I didn't see any obvious problem in your code.

Comment: Hey, the reason why my code crashed was because the user did not have authentication to write to the database! I wasnt getting this in an error message however

Comment: So, you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes thanks. I had no write access to the database so this is why I could'nt create the category